# Reading CSV file with specific format to calculate Inner Annotator Agreement?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file consist of text and three annotator results for the same text...
Example:

```
textA  anno1
textA  anno2
textA  anno3
textB  anno1
textB  anno2
textB  anno3
...   ...
```

and so on..
I want to save the anno1 in array1, anno2 in array2 and anno3 in array3 to calculate the Inner Annotator Agreement...
How I can do that in python?

Comment: What does "Inner Annotator Agreement" mean? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Iam trying to measure how the annotators match in their answer..

Comment: this link may help you https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I have no code, I am working on csv file format to find a way to do that...